# How to create an animation with matplotlib scatter plots with each frame defined by lists for markers and colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create an animation in matplotlib using the `FuncAnimation` method from matplotlib. The pseudo code is something like:

```
# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the initial frame
sc = ax.scatter([0], [0], s=20, marker="o", c="w", alpha=0.5)

# Function to update the plot in each animation frame
def update(frame):
    global sc

    # Method that returns the actual data to plot. Each variable is
    # a list with the same length containing the x/y value, the color (as "b", "r", ...)
    # and the marker (like "o", "^", ...)
    new_x, new_y, new_colors, new_markers = get_data_by_time(frame)

    # Clear previous scatter plot
    sc.remove()

    # Update scatter plot with new markers
    for i, marker in enumerate(new_markers):
        sc._offsets[i] = new_x[i], new_y[i]  # Update the position
        sc._sizes[i] = 10  
        sc._facecolors[i] = new_colors[i]  
        sc._edgecolors[i] = 'black'  # Example: set black edge color
        sc._marker = marker  # Set the marker type


# Create the animation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(100), interval=50)

# Save the animation as a GIF
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='pillow', fps=20)
```

The problems are in the update function:

- It uses a global which does not seem pythonic. But it seems it cannot work any other way
- Is there no other way to create a scatter plot when having a list of x values, y values, colors and markers? The `sc` seem to have a `set_offsets` method to update all x/y values, it has a `set_color` method to update all colors, but it does not seem to have a `set_markers` method
- in the code above I get an error:

  ```
    sc._facecolors[i] = new_colors[i]  # Update the color
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'k'
  ```

  I thought I define colors with letters like 'b', 'r', 'k'. But here I need floats?

Is there some way to get this to work?